# order by on last column of composite index

Tags: oracle

There is a composite index on ColA, colB and colC in oracle database.
The query looks like this ->

```
where colA = ? and colB is null 
order by colC
```

it seems null / not null checks don't hit index so colB is of no use, but condition on `colA = ?` hits index.
But , will Order by on colC get advantage from composite index above given that colB is of no use due to null check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A composite index indexes all the columns together as one entity. It does not index each of the columns separately. So sorting order will not use the index. You need to add an index on that column.

Comment: Thanks Racil, another question -> If colB is removed from composite index, then will orderBy clause use index for query provided in question ? Secondly, if there were 2 indexes - one on colA and another on ColC, then will Oracle use colA index for WHERE condition as well as colC index for orderBy or one of the two ?

Comment: You should post new questions, not comments to the same question. Also keep in mind that the engine selects the best way to run queries, so just because you have an index, doesn't mean it will be used. Removing colB doesn't change much. In both cases Oracle may use the composite index, but with `FULL SCAN`. In most cases, adding an index on the single colC column performs better. If you create 2 indexes, one for colA and one for colB then Oracle will use them in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`.